# How to tracking process's status in Tibco?

Tags: process, tracking, tibco

I hope you show me resolve in my case.

1. When I define many process, how to get status data's tracking of that process. In other word, I want to get process's history. My purpose to show for my client checking.
2. I have defined a process communicate 3 applications and i deploy it to client.but unfortunately, my client would like to add more an application ( up to 4 apps) in the future. i wonder if how to do that? i perhaps open process again and edit it. Have a way create dynamic process.

Thanks very much.

PVA.

Comment: What TIBCO tool exactgly are you talking about: BusinessWorks, iProcess, AMX BPM, ...?

Comment: I use BusinessWorks tool

Answer (score 1):

1. You get a very limited "history" in TIBCO Administator (more or less which process instances completed with success/failure; in case of failure it will also provided the exception and where in the process it failed).  However that doesn't show you any tracking of the individual steps/activities that the process passed through.  For this, you'd either have to put lots of logging steps into your process (and need to build something that parses this information from log files).  Or you could use BusinessWorks ProcessMonitoring, which gives you a full history trail for each process automatically.  However it not included with BW and you'll probably need a separate license.
2. Change the process in TIBCO Designer, build a new ear file, re-deploy the new EAR file in TIBCO Administrator.

Comment: Thanks for your information. I created a process in Tibco Designer, how to start it from C# application?